# Why does the stackoverflow.com/index.php [index page] page open a YouTube page?

Tags: discussion

Today I noticed a very weird thing. https://stackoverflow.com/index.php redirects to YouTube.

What is the proper reason?

Comment: It's joke. Stack Overflow is not built with PHP, so attempting to load `index.php` would not make sense. Users attempting reach that URL are being [rickrolled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling).

Comment: @yivi _Bots_ attempting to _crawl_ it are getting rickrolled.

Comment: [This is the context](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1245837249880690688) (AFAIK - at least _some_ context)